# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'texty'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm experimenting for the first time in Python trying out the language, I picked up Kivy as my GUI library of choice and I got it working partially. However it doesn't seem to recognize a defined function even though I have set it as a global variable.

```
import psutil
import time
import threading
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b = BoxLayout()
        self.texty = Label(text=str(psutil.cpu_percent()))
        b.add_widget(self.texty)
        return b

    def update(self):
            self.texty.text = str(psutil.cpu_percent())

    Clock.schedule_interval(update, 1.0)

ExampleApp().run()
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\Python Projects\Kivy\main.py", line 21, in <module>
     ExampleApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\K0vac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\K0vac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\K0vac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\K0vac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\K0vac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "C:\Users\K0vac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 591, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "D:\Python Projects\Kivy\main.py", line 17, in update
     self.texty.text = str(psutil.cpu_percent())
 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'texty'
```

Any ideas on how to solve this error? Thanks!

Comment: Where is that `Clock` line meant to be, the indentation is wrong.

Comment: @AMC even if that fixed is corrected the problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the problem make the following change:

```py
def update(self):
    print(self)
```

And you'll see that you get the following:

```
# ...
0.995747223001672
0.9959899680106901
0.9982999769854359
0.9948770129994955
# ...
```

Why is `self` a number and not the instance of the class? Well, because in the scope where you use Clock, it behaves like a function and `schedule_interval()` passes as the first parameter the time it runs that as you see almost coincides with the period of 1.0 seconds.

So the solution is better to use schedule_interval within the methods such as in build:

```
import psutil

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b = BoxLayout()
        self.texty = Label(text=str(psutil.cpu_percent()))
        b.add_widget(self.texty)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0)
        return b

    def update(self, dt):
        self.texty.text = str(psutil.cpu_percent())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks so much!